# Is ecwid-mailchimp library thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, mailchimp

I am integrating my Spring based web application with MailChimp using this [library](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/wiki)

The a comment in the sample code shown on it's wiki home page says:

> // reuse the same MailChimpClient object whenever possible

As per this advice, I'm using the MailChimpClient object as an instance variable in a class annotated with @Service, however, this is causing exceptions in the server log which make me think this class may not be thread-safe. Can anyone confirm?

Exception stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:162) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:139) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:456) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784) ~[httpclient-4.2.3.jar:4.2.3]
at com.ecwid.mailchimp.connection.HttpClientConnectionManager.post(HttpClientConnectionManager.java:63) ~[ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.0.jar:na]
at com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpClient.execute(MailChimpClient.java:74) ~[ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.0.jar:na]
at com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpClient.execute(MailChimpClient.java:83) ~[ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.0.jar:na]
at com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpClient.execute(MailChimpClient.java:95) ~[ecwid-mailchimp-2.0.1.0.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**: instances of MailChimpClient are not thread safe and therefore should not be shared among threads.

The long answer: it depends on implementation of MailChimpConnectionManager passed to the constructor. If that implementation is thread safe, then MailChimpClient instance is thread safe as well. However, existing implementations (HttpClientConnectionManager, JavaNetURLConnectionManager) are **not** thread safe.

Thus, if you really need MailChimpClient be shared among threads, you could write your own (thread safe) implementation of MailChimpConnectionManager and pass it to the constructor.